# Insert file into access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named `Reports` which has 3 fields `ID` (auto number), `filename` (string field), `theFile` (attachment field).

What I want to is to run a SQL query and insert a PDF file into the attachments field (`theFile`).

Lets say the PDF file is located in the C: drive (C:\report1.pdf), I have tried the SQL query below but it is not working. I know its not good practice to store files in a database but I just want to try it out:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Reports (filename,theFile) VALUES ('report1'," & C:\report1.pdf & ")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standard practice to store files in a database. Access certainly supports it, but not through SQL. You'll have to use DAO, as detailed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258184%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"File" is not appropriate SQL data type supported in Access, [available data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That is correct Derek, if you try to run a SQL statement like that you will get an error message of one type or another every time.  I spent a fair amount of time researching this subject for my own DB, and from what I understand there are a number of options/alternatives; however, having an attachment column type and using SQL to insert a file is not an option with Access' current capabilities.

It is not bad practice to store files in a database, it is actually standard practice; however, it IS best practice to not store files in an ACCESS db. There are a few reasons for this which you can research on your own, but perhaps most notably, Access has a file size limit of 2GB, so if you store files in it you can run out of space quickly and then things get even more complicated.

Here are your options:

1. Change your column data type to OLE object and use some kind of stream reader to convert the files to binary data, then use a SQL statement to load them into your DB
2. Use the built in Access user interface for working directly with tables/attachments
3. Establish a DAO db connection and use Access' recordset.LoadFromFile function
4. Just store links to the files in the Access DB

The 4th option is the preferred method. It's very simple and you won't have to worry about complex code or the 2GB storage limit.