# Attaching a data source and pictures to a databse using sql command

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm working on an assignment where we are building a housing database. One of my group members sent me code she described as "Not working" and I've fixed it up to a point however, I'm not too familiar with sql command and I still feel that a few things are off here.

Here's the code for inserting:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = Initial Catolog = House_accdb; Integrated Security = true");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Units_With_Tenants(Address, Bedroom, Bathroom, Tenant_Name, Preferences, Picture, Proposed_Rate) VALUES(@Address, @Bedroom, @Bathroom, @Tenant_Name, @Preferences, @Picture, @Proposed_Rate)");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bedroom", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bathroom", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tenant_Name", textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Preferences", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", File.ReadAllBytes(richTextBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Proposed_Rate", textBox7.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error. Please enter all fields", "Info");
        }
    }
```

And also here's the code for me attempting to place a picture in the database.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PictureBox PictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
                PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Are you using Access or MySQL as your RDBMS? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180179/insert-file-into-access-table) question might be helpful if you are using Access.

Comment: Using Access. It helped somewhat thanks but I am still confused by it however.

Comment: Basically the way you are trying to save the attachment doesn't work because you're attempting it within a SQL statement and Access doesn't allow that. As for how to make it work with DAO, I don't know C#, so I don't know how to port it correctly. Without C#, it would be written as a VBA script to save the file to a specific row in your table.